# Create Filtered XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, xml

I have XML data containing image information.  My first goal is to create a filtered `XmlNodeList` (ex. return all of the images where `color == yellow`).  The ultimate goal is to be able to return a list of names of images where `color == yellow` (returning an entire filtered `XmlNodeList` is great, but I will really just need one element within that filtered list, such as a name or id).

In my case, the root node is called `Images`, and I want to be able to search amongst each `Image` node.  My XML data has no XML attributes, so every bit of data is represented as an element (making the color 'yellow' a child node of an image, not an attribute of an image).

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Images xmlns="http://oec.api.opsource.net/schemas/server"
    xmlns:ns9="http://oec.api.opsource.net/schemas/multigeo"
    xmlns:ns5="http://oec.api.opsource.net/schemas/vip"
    xmlns:ns12="http://oec.api.opsource.net/schemas/storage"
    xmlns:ns6="http://oec.api.opsource.net/schemas/whitelabel"
    xmlns:ns13="http://oec.api.opsource.net/schemas/manualimport"
    xmlns:ns7="http://oec.api.opsource.net/schemas/datacenter"
    xmlns:ns10="http://oec.api.opsource.net/schemas/reset"
    xmlns:ns8="http://oec.api.opsource.net/schemas/general"
    xmlns:ns11="http://oec.api.opsource.net/schemas/support"
    xmlns:ns2="http://oec.api.opsource.net/schemas/directory"
    xmlns:ns4="http://oec.api.opsource.net/schemas/network"
    xmlns:ns3="http://oec.api.opsource.net/schemas/organization">
    <Image>
        <id>mcd93jf8dd</id>
        <name>cat</name>
        <color>yellow</color>
    </Image>
    <Image>
        <id>d4b8l23sas</id>
        <name>dog</name>
        <color>yellow</color>
    </Image>
</Images>
```

My original source of XML data is a stream.  I have figured out ways of iterating through the different levels of my XML hierarchy using foreach loops, but I keep running into issues of not having all the methods available that I need on child nodes.  Advice elsewhere seems to suggest using `XPath` to implement my filter, but I could not get that to work with what I have got thus far:

C#

```
//'stream' previously defined as a Stream
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(reader);
XmlElement root = xml.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList images = root.ChildNodes;

foreach (XmlNode image in images) {

    XmlNodeList attributes = image.ChildNodes;

    foreach (XmlNode attribute in attributes) {
        //do stuff
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've posted some code here: http://ideone.com/jRFoBW to demonstrate the below techniques. It shouldn't make a difference whether the XML is loaded from a stream or directly from a string, but I've set it up to load from a stream to mimic your conditions as closely as possible.

Since your XML uses a namespace, you'll need to create a namespace manager and add the namespace to it:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
// The prefix can be anything as long as you use it consistently
nsm.AddNamespace("i", "http://oec.api.opsource.net/schemas/server");
```

Then you can do the following to get lists of yellow `id`s and `name`s:

```
XmlNodeList ids = xml.SelectNodes("/i:Images/i:Image[i:color = 'yellow']/i:id", nsm);
XmlNodeList names = xml.SelectNodes("/i:Images/i:Image[i:color = 'yellow']/i:name", nsm);
```

Though if you want both the `id` and `name` for yellow images, I would suggest doing:

```
foreach(XmlNode yellowImage in xml.SelectNodes("/i:Images/i:Image[i:color = 'yellow']", nsm))
{
   string id = yellowImage.SelectSingleNode("i:id", nsm).InnerText;
   string name = yellowImage.SelectSingleNode("i:name", nsm).InnerText;

   // use id and name
}
```

Comment: The code compiles, but when I test it I get no results.  Using the first approach, when I did ids.Count, it returned 0.  When I did the foreach loop and added Console.Writeline(id) within the loop, there was no output.

Comment: I would expect it to work, given that input XML.  Could you inspect the value of `xml.OuterXml` to ensure it's the same as the XML above?  Perhaps there's a namespace declaration?

Comment: The actual XML data I am working with does include a XML declaration and namespace.  I will have to investigate further if that has an effect, as you are suggesting.

Comment: Could you share the actual root tag (which I'm assuming is the `<Images>` tag) with all its namespace declarations?

Comment: Creating a namespace manager still left me with the same result.  The code compiles, but I am getting XmlNodeLists with no elements.

Comment: Did you also incorporate the other modifications I indicated above?  You need to use the namespace prefix throughout and pass the namespace manager to the SelectNodes() method.

Comment: Yep.  I had never seen that syntax before, but I used the "i" prefix as you did, and inscribed it in all the appropriate places, I believe.  I think the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I've put the code up here so you can experiment with it: http://ideone.com/jRFoBW  I put the string into a Stream first to reproduce your conditions as closely as possible, and it runs as expected.  Please have a look.

Comment: The problem is definitely related to namespaces.  When I created a XML file with my exact data, but removed the namespaces, the code worked fine.  My plan now is to either (1) remove the namespaces from my data before I query it, or (2) impose some sort of default namespace so that I can ignore the namespaces which are in place in the original XML data.

Comment: Your code works.  I was adding multiple namespaces incorrectly.  The link you sent helped me realize the problem.  Thanks!