# XML reading and writing - How's best for multi level nodes

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write to and pull from an XML document some timing marks within an audio track. I've came up with the following XML file but I'm not sure how I have it set out is the best way to go about it.

```
<Production>
  <Name>Jekyll and Hyde</Name>
  <StartDate>1/1/20</StartDate>
  <EndDate>10/10/25</EndDate>
  <Tracks>
    <Track>
      <Name>Track Name 1</Name>
      <Artist>Unknown Artist</Artist>
      <Production>Jekyll and Hyde</Production>
      <LyricTimings>
        <Lyric>This is the first line</Lyric>
        <Time>000.00</Time>
      </LyricTimings>
      <LyricTimings>
        <Lyric>This is the second line</Lyric>
        <Time>002.18</Time>
      </LyricTimings>
      <LyricTimings>
        <Lyric>This is the third line</Lyric>
        <Time>004.20</Time>
      </LyricTimings>
    </Track>
    <Track>
      <Name>Track Name 2</Name>
      <Artist>Unknown</Artist>
      <Production>Jekyll and Hyde</Production>
      <LyricTimings>
        <Lyric>This is the first line of track 2</Lyric>
        <Time>002.00</Time>
      </LyricTimings>
      <LyricTimings>
        <Lyric>This is the second line of track 2</Lyric>
        <Time>004.00</Time>
      </LyricTimings>
    </Track>
  </Tracks>
</Production>
```

What I am looking to do is pull the Lyric Timings into a list box so as when we click on a lyric we can be taken straight to that point in the song.

The VB code I have so far is:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
        doc.Load(path)

        For Each Node As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("/Production/Tracks/Track")
            lstTracks.Items.Add(Node.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText)
        Next
```

This above loads all the track titles into the first list box. On click of a track in the first list box I wish the second list box to populate with all it's lyrics taken from the XML so as when I click a lyric it uses the time to go to the right point in the track.

Is the way the XML is set out correct or is there a better way? What's the code I should be using to populate my second list box with the Lyric Tracks on a selection of a track in the first list box?

Many thanks!

Comment: "Better" is always relative.  I use XML for some things myself, but I wouldn't use it for everything.  Have you thought about how much data you're ultimately going to have, if XML data processing is going to be effective at that scale, how much memory it will take etc.?  That said, I'd probably create a Lyrics subnode for each track that has all the LyricTimings in it for that track, then you can look at `/Production/Tracks/Track/Lyrics` for a given track.

Comment: For examples on filtering, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341134/how-can-i-filter-xmlnodelist) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283105/create-filtered-xmlnodelist).  There are other entries here on SO about filtering, using LINQ etc.